# Mysql:Query for the table as below

Tags: mysql, concatenation, user-defined-functions, string-concatenation

I have the following table:

```
|-------------------|
| id | Homephone    |
|-------------------|
| 1  | 454454125    |
| 2  | 47872154587  |
| 3  | 128795423    |
| 4  | 148784474    |
|-------------------|
```

I have around 40.000 rows in the table.

I want to format `Homephone` values as following:

```
454-454-125 
478-721-545-87
128-795-423
148-784-474
```

i.e. after every 3 numbers I want `-` (hyphen).
How to achieve this using MySQL?

Comment: what is your current mysql code? What have you tried? If it is for a website, do you happen to be using a server-side language? (PHP, JSP, Python, Perl...)

Comment: in PHP application i want this one

Comment: but in phpmyadmin i created table without hyphon(-) for homephone column but i want to change now.........

Answer (score 1):

You need to wite a [udf](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-functions.html) for this

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to create your own function (so called [UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) - User Defined Function) and run it on the table.
There is a nice function by Andrew Hanna posted in [String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) chapter of the MySQL Reference Manual. I fixed a small mistake there (replaced `WHILE (i < str_len) DO` by `WHILE (i <= str_len) DO`.
There are two steps (two SQL queries):

1. Create the function. It has three parameters: `str` - the string to be modified, `pos` - position of the character being inserted into the string, `delimit` - character(s) to be inserted:

   ```
   DELIMITER //
   CREATE FUNCTION insert_characters(str text, pos int, delimit varchar(124))
   RETURNS text
   DETERMINISTIC
   BEGIN
       DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
       DECLARE str_len INT;
       DECLARE out_str text default '';
       SET str_len = length(str);
       WHILE (i <= str_len) DO
           SET out_str = CONCAT(out_str, SUBSTR(str, i, pos), delimit);
           SET i = i + pos; 
       END WHILE;
       -- trim delimiter from end of string
       SET out_str = TRIM(trailing delimit from out_str);
       RETURN(out_str);
   END//
   DELIMITER ;
   ```
2. Run the function...

   - ...for testing purpose (select, no update):

     ```
     SELECT insert_characters(Homephone, 3, "-") AS new_phone FROM my_table;
     ```
   - ...to update the records:

     ```
     UPDATE my_table SET Homephone = insert_characters(Homephone, 3, "-");
     ```

Please try to analyze the function line by line. This example may help you to understand the subject.